# NoClassDefFoundError exception when calling Java code from Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

I created a Kotlin project and Java class in it:

```
package text;

public class StringUtils {

    public static void filter(boolean flag) {
        System.out.println("Flag is " + flag);
    }
}
```

Then I tried to call filter method from the Kotlin code:

```
val exists = true;
StringUtils.filter(exists)
```

I didn't see any errors in my Intellij IDE but in run-time I got an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: text/StringUtils
    at Person.printName(Person.kt:66)
    at PersonKt.main(Person.kt:103)
    at PersonKt.main(Person.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: text.StringUtils
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 3 more
```

- Kotlin compiler: 1.4.30
- IDE: Intellij 2020.3.2
- JDK: 15.0.1

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine. Make sure you put the java class inside the Java folder and not Kotlin folder.

Comment: Thank you. After I moved TextUtils into src/main/java folder the code was run properly. But I guess Intellij should display errors/warnings if I put Java class into src/main/kotlin folder and try to use it in the Kotlin code

Comment: You can configure the building system to look for both java and Kolton files in the same directories. I guess that's why the IDE doesn't show it as error.

Comment: Yes, IDEA should warn, please watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-1233 for updates on this.

Answer (score 24):

You have to put all Java classes under *src/main/java*, instead of *src/main/kotlin*.

Just right click on main -> new -> directory -> select java (or type it).

Comment: You are a lifesaver.